# SQL Server export stored procedure results to CSV file keeping char(9) format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm having a problem with exporting the results of a stored procedure to a csv file and keeping the results as a 9 character string. The results of the stored procedure is a simple one column output which looks fine when executed in SSMS but the returned values in the csv that have leading zeros are being returned without the zeros. The table column is type `varchar(13)` and I have done a convert to try and keep the leading zeros from being dropped but no luck.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
convert(char(8),n.NIIN)
FROM IMMS_ELEC.dbo.NIINList n
```

Here is the simple BCP script I'm using:

```
DECLARE @string AS NVARCHAR(4000)
SELECT    @string = 'BCP "exec CPLINK_Dev.dbo.spSelectLOG_NiinDistinct"
QUERYOUT:\data.csv -c -T -t'
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @string
```

Comment: Try SELECT DISTINCT '"'+convert(char(8),n.NIIN)+'"' FROM IMMS_ELEC.dbo.NIINList n.     If you add a quote to either side, CSV should see it as text and keep leading zeros

Comment: I tried that but the results are the same.

Comment: What program are you opening the CSV with?   If you open it with notepad, are the leading zeroes there?   Excel will "help" you by converting them to numbers

Comment: @Sparky, if I open it in Notepad ++, I get the 9 character output I expect. If I open it in Excel, the leading zeros are dropped. Interesting.

Comment: It means the problem is not in your SQL output, but rather Excel.   Try adding a single quote in front and see if that allows Excel to view it as text...

Comment: @Sparky, That seems to work except that there are only 2450 rows in the excel sheet but if I edit in Notepad ++ there are 4901 rows which is correct. Is there a limitation in Excel I wonder? I copied the code to generate the csv so I'm also not sure what the switches do so I will research that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Some older versions of Excel have limits, but not that low...  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Excel loves to think it knows how to format your data better than you do... Here's a trick you can use to outsmart it. Open a new spreadsheet, select all cells and change the type to text (from general), then copy your data from notepad (or SSMS), paste it into Excel, and use text to columns if you have to... Excel should stop messing with your formats then.

You can also probably do the same thing with import data from Excel, but I find the first much more effective and you can use it to copy and paste directly from SSMS grid results as well.